# Transaction Visibility Issue: Main Thread Transactions not Visible in Spawned Threads

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, rate-limiting

I am conducting rate-limiting testing for an application. To achieve this, I'm mocking a request on the main thread and attempting to retrieve it in spawned threads, but I'm encountering difficulties. While I can successfully retrieve the data on the main thread both before and after the mock request of the thread, I'm unable to do so in the spawned threads. The provided code snippet demonstrates the main thread patching the 'Endpoint_1' and the spawned threads attempting to perform Endpoint_2. However, during the execution of the thread mock request, the 'Endpoint_1' insertion appears null. How can I resolve this issue and successfully retrieve the patched data in the spawned threads?"

```
AuthenticationResponseDto authenticationResponse = CommonTests.signIn(mockMvc, Helpers.formulateTestUser());

Endpoint_1_Dto endpoint_1_Dto= Helpers.getEndpoint_1_Dto();

mockMvc.perform(patch("/dummy/endpoint_1")
        .headers(Helpers.formulateHeaders(authenticationResponse, ENDPOINT_1_ROLE))
        .content(Jackson.toJsonString(endpoint_1_Dto))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();

for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_THREADS_NO; i++) {
    int threadNo = i;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Endpoint_2_Dto endpoint_2_Dto = Helpers.getEndpoint_2_Dto();

            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/dummy/endpoint_2").headers(httpHeaders)
                    .content(Jackson.toJsonString(endpoint_2_Dto))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andReturn();

            int responseHttpCode = result.getResponse().getStatus();

            if (responseHttpCode != HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value()) {
                failCount.incrementAndGet(); // failCount will be used for assertion later
            }

            log.info("Response from Thread " + threadNo + " is: " + responseHttpCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Caught exception of type: " + e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

During the execution of the thread mock request, it the Endpoint_1 insertion is null, which is patched by the main thread. So how to resolve this.

I logged the data retrieved on the main thread before spawning and after joining the thread. The data patched by the main thread mock request is retrieved successfully. However, when I log in spawn threads, it returns null. I expect the main thread transactions to be reflected in spawn threads and vice versa.